# Display free folder space

Tags: powershell

I am creating a menu and have a option that displays the computer name and os version and a option that displays the disk space. I need to have the options to be done on a local or a remote machine. It works on the local machine but I am not sure how to allow the options to be done on a remote machine

```
'1' {
         cls
                Write-Host -NoNewLine "OS Version: "

  Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object  Caption | ForEach{ $_.Caption }

  Write-Host ""
  Write-Host -NoNewLine "Computer Name: "

  Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object  CSName | ForEach{ $_.CSName }

  Write-Host ""
           } '2' {
                cls
                   gwmi win32_logicaldisk | Format-Table DeviceId, MediaType, @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}},@{n="FreeSpace";e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have already mentioned that it is working in your local, I am not touching that part. Just wrap that entire code as a *Function* with *$ComputerName* as Parameters.

If you are in a domain admin or if you do not have any permission issue, then with the same credentials you can fetch the information remotely.

**Use like this:**

```
function Get-DiskInfo($drive,$computername)
{

 ##-- Local system Validation
    if((gwmi win32_computersystem).Name -eq $computername)
    {
        $diskReport = Get-WmiObject Win32_logicaldisk
        $drive = $diskReport | Where-Object { $_.DeviceID -eq $drive}

        $result = @{
            Size = $drive.Size
            FreeSpace = $drive.Freespace
        }
        return $result
    }
    else
    {

            $diskReport = Get-WmiObject Win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $ComputerName
            $drive = $diskReport | Where-Object { $_.DeviceID -eq $drive}

            $result = @{
            Size = $drive.Size
            FreeSpace = $drive.Freespace
            }
            return $result

    }



}
```

Call the function:

```
  Get-DiskInfo C: localhost
```

Since you are using all WMI calls , you do not need to use *Invoke-Command*.
You can directly use the *-ComputerName* switch present in the *get-wmiobject* to fetch all the details remotely and you can pass the specific credentials also as *-credential*

Hope it helps you understand the logic.